# Gridsearch through multiple models and parameters

Tags: python, machine-learning, pipeline, training-data, grid-search

please view my pipeline below, i get an error but i cannot understand why:

```
n_estimators = [12,60]
min_samples_leaf = [2, 4]

models = {
    'DecisionTreeClassifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(),
    'RandomForestClassifier': RandomForestClassifier(),
    'NaiveBayes': GaussianNB(),
    'LogisticRegression': LogisticRegression()
}

params= {
    'DecisionTreeClassifier':{ 

            "max_depth":[2,4,6,8,10],
            "criterion": ['gini', 'entropy'],

            },
    'RandomForestClassifier': {
        'n_estimators': n_estimators, 
        'min_samples_leaf': min_samples_leaf

        },
    'NaiveBayes': {

        },  
    'LogisticRegression':{
        'C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000] #Regularization Coefficnet


    }
}

for name in models.keys():

    est = models[name]
    est_params = params[name] # in cross validation we are really only traning the model on a small portion of the data
    pipeline = Pipeline([('imputation', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),('model',models[name])])
    gscv = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=est_params, cv=5,return_train_score=True) #return_train_score=False
    gscv.fit(x_train_values, y_train)
```

however i get an error: **ValueError: Invalid parameter criterion for estimator Pipeline(memory=None,**

i am not sure why i am getting this error, i have tried to break it down by looking at one classifier e.g.:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([('imputation', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),('model',models['LogisticRegression'])])
gscv = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=params['LogisticRegression'], cv=5,return_train_score=True) #return_train_score=False
gscv.fit(x_train_values, y_train)
```

however it is the same error. i have also tried to get what i should be calling that parameter but it ouputs what i already have up there (C)

```
for param in models['LogisticRegression'].get_params().keys():
    print(param)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider this `df`:

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame([['?', "Don't change"], ['!', '<']], columns=['col1', 'col2'])
print(df)

>>> 
  col1          col2
0    ?  Don't change
1    !             <
```

If you want to replace `['?', '!', '>']` in every colum you can use regex like this:

```py
updated_df = df.replace(r'\?|<', 'replace_value', regex=True)
print(updated_df)

>>>
            col1           col2
0  replace_value   Don't change
1  replace_value  replace_value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary for replacing values in dataframe. Following is an example:-

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a': ['>','a'], 'b': ['a','?']})
```

You can replace it by doing:-

```
df.replace({'a':{'>',""},'b':{'?',""}},regex = True)
```